# How to make a mechanical elevator with rotation?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How can I make an elevator that goes up while twisting like in [this video](https://youtu.be/KCElBEfwLfc)? (The man that made this used an old printer)

Comment: [lead screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leadscrew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it looks like the lift and rotation elements are mechanically separate ie the lift mechanism sits on a rotating turntable.

Here the key element is to be able to provide electrical power to a rotating assembly, I can't see in detail how this is done in this particular case but [slip rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring) would be the conventional solution.